# python Загрузка нескольких документов в vk

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как организовать загрузку на сервер VK нескольких файлов, скажем *.xz, используя [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api)? 
Для загрузки одиночного файла я использовал:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import vk_api


def main():

    login, p, grp, token = '*', '*', '*', '*'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, p, token, captcha_handler=captcha_handler)

    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return

    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)

    filepath= input('File path: ')

    doc = upload.document(  # Подставьте свои данные
        filepath,
        title=filepath.split("/")[-1],
        tags=None,
        group_id=grp
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Используйте класс [`VkUpload`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload) и его метод [`document`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload.document).

Comment: @nomnoms12 , это очевидно, его я и использовал(см. изменение). Мне же нужно организовать загрузку всех файлов в папке, имеющих одинаковое расширение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться модулем `glob` и его методом `glob` для поиска файлов по некоторой маске, например `*.xz`, и отдельно загрузить каждый файл.

***Пример:***

```py
import glob
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.upload import VkUpload


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi(login='...', password='...')
    vk_session.auth()
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    upload = VkUpload(vk)

    for file in glob.glob('*.xz'):
        doc = upload.document(file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```